# Insert node at current position of doubly linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I have a doubly linked list, let's say it's like this:

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  node_t *prev, *next;
} node_t;
```

It has been set up, pushed to, etc. Let's say it contains 20 values.

```
node_t *foo = malloc(sizeof(node_t));   // the actual list
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    push(&foo, i+1);
```

I have some more code that gets my list to a certain point. Let's say it gets it to index 12:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    foo = foo->next;
```

Now I want to insert a node at the current position in the list. So currently my list is like this:

```
index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
value: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
                                              ^ current position
```

Inserting a node with, say, value `8` here should turn it into this:

```
index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
value: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 8,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
                                              ^ current position
```

I'm using this to insert the node (error checks excluded):

```
void insert_at_start(node_t **head, int val)
{
    node_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    newnode->data = val;
    newnode->next = (*head);
    (*head) = newnode;
}
```

However, that doesn't preserve any data to the left of the current position; only to the right. It turns the list into this:

```
index: 0, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8
value: 8, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
       ^ current position
```

How can I modify `insert_at_start` (changing it to `insert_at_current`) so it preserves the left side of the list, without assuming I know what index the list is at?

Comment: You've not set the new node's `prev` element, so you've broken your list.  You've also not updated the `prev` pointer in the element after the new node; it needs to point to the new node. The `next` pointer of the previous node needs to point to the new node too.  But you need to set the new node's `prev` pointer first: `newnode->prev = (*head)->prev; (*head)->prev = newnode; newnode->prev->next = newnode;` — and you may need to worry about insertion before the first node (null pointers).

Comment: In your `insert_at_start` function, add this - `newnode->prev = newnode->next->prev;` after this statement `newnode->next = (*head);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46867795/insert-node-at-current-position-of-doubly-linked-list#comment80683033_46867795) from Jonathan Leffler, implemented [here](https://github.com/aaronryank/ecpp/blob/master/src/token.c#L74):

```
void add_at_current(token_t **current, int val)
{
    if (!(*current)) {
        (*current) = malloc(sizeof(token_t));
        (*current)->val = val;
        (*current)->next = NULL;
        (*current)->prev = NULL;
        return;
    }

    token_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(token_t));

    newnode->val = val;
    newnode->prev = (*current)->prev;
    (*current)->prev = newnode;
    newnode->prev->next = newnode;
    newnode->next = (*current);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Say your current position is the node at index 11.

You wish to insert between index 11 and index 12.
 Assuming head is pointing to the node at index 11.

```
  void insert_at_start(node_t **head, int val)
    {
        node_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

        newnode->data = val;

        //insert between two node eg. node 11 and 12
        node_t *n_11 = *head;        // node 11
        node_t *n_12 = (*head)->next; // node 12

        n_11->next = newnode;
        n_12->prev = newnode;

        newnode->next = n_12;
        newnode->prev = n_11;

        (*head) = newnode;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Making minimal changes to your code for insert_at_start

```
void insert_at_current(node_t **head, int index, int val)
{   
  node_t *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

  node_t *current = *head;
  for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) //bring current to the point where you need it to
     current = current ->next;

  newnode->next = current->next; //set the next of the new node
  newnode->prev = current; //set the prev of the new node
  newnode->data = val;
  current->next->prev=newnode //set the prev of the node after the one we insert
  current->next=newnode; //set the next of the current node


}
```

Also, as many pointed out in the comment you should not forget to set the prev of the newnode to null and the prev of your list head to newnode in the insert_at_start function